# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element using ChromeDriver Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wish to load the [2048 game](http://2048game.com/), and click on ***Down*** key.
I have tried the below code:

```
driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://2048game.com");
String path="/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

`path` is the xpath of the left most upper tile.

Also tried `.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);` and it did not help as well.

It successfully loads the page, but **it does not press the** `DownKey`?

My code in console complains with:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 38 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-BD6AOVKQ', ip: '192.168.1.208', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41), userDataDir=C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir23108_15057}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=69.0.3497.100, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 6be1718d9dbeddfa7508d895eb40a10c
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:96)
    at services.Hook.<init>(Hook.java:27)
    at mains.Online2048.main(Online2048.java:9)
```

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs ?

Comment: @njosep updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I have tried same code on firefox browser. Please have a look and it's working.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class geckodriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {




        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
//      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
//      capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
//      
//      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capabilities.setVersion("your firefox version");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

    //  driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        driver.get("http://2048game.com");
        String path="/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div";
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        System.out.println("Done");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
}}
```

Comment: what do you receive if you try it on `chrome`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on error message an element you are trying to apply sendKeys to is not focused - thus ChromeDriver fails to interact with it.

In case you just want to press arrow down the following code should work (just changed the xPath from your example):

```
driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://2048game.com");
String path="//*";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to **focus** on the desired *WebElement*.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.30*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.30*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.30/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v58-60**

- You are using *chrome=69.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.4.0** which is a bit older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_171** which is also a bit older.

So there is a clear mismatch between the **JDK v8u171** , **Selenium Client v3.4.0** , **ChromeDriver v2.36** and the **Chrome Browser v69.0**

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 0):

**Found solution using chromeDriver.**

```
        driver.get("http://2048game.com");
        WebElement e1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]"));
        e1.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        System.out.println("Done");
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the focus on the element before sending keys to it.

In order to fix it, we can use Selenium Actions:

```
Actions assigner = new Actions(webdriver);
assigner.moveToElement(webelement);
assigner.click();
assigner.sendKeys("<your value>");
assigner.build().perform();
```